# jQuery extract span text with added character

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one html code that looks like this:

```
<span class="itemprop" itemprop="name">AAA aaa</span>
<span class="itemprop" itemprop="name">BBB bbb</span>
<span class="itemprop" itemprop="name">CCC ccc</span>
```

i use this code to extract values from span:

```
$('span.itemprop').text();
```

But i get this from output:

```
AAA aaaBBB bbbCCC ccc
```

And need to get this:

```
AAA aaa BBB bbb CCC ccc
```

How can i get this output?

Comment: $('span.itemprop').each(function(){  texts+= "  "+$(this).text();  });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st :** use `each function` to get the text and `concatenate` it like this

**2nd :** Extra space will removed by using `trim()`

```
 var texts="";
$('span.itemprop').each(function(){  texts+= $(this).text()+" ";  });
```

```js
var texts="";
$('span.itemprop').each(function(){  texts+= $(this).text()+" ";  });
console.log(texts.length);
console.log(texts = $.trim(texts));
console.log(texts.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="itemprop" itemprop="name">AAA aaa</span>
<span class="itemprop" itemprop="name">BBB bbb</span>
<span class="itemprop" itemprop="name">CCC ccc</span>
```

Comment: Thanks runs perfect...just added .replace so that first AA does not begin with space..thanks it works excellent.

Comment: just use $.trim(texts); . i updated my answer take a look on it .